# Out-of-band Sql Injection

Tags: exploit, sql-injection

When I was doing some security research, I found an unexpected query in a POST request like this:

```
q=select%20*%20from%20x%20where%20a%20%3D%20'%7B%22something%22%3A%22blah%22%2C...%7D'
```

Where the decoded content is:

```
q=select * from x where a = '{"something":"blah",...}'
```

And the requested endpoint is: `/v2/public/yql?...`

After I saw this, I was thinking about SQL Injection. But there is a problem: The response of this request is always **204 No Content**, even after I have changed the query (SQL Injection, blind SQL Injection).

Do anyone know how to exploit SQL injection in this situation? Is this vulnerable? What does the endpoint mean? 
*Note: this is the Yahoo page, and that is the Yahoo Query Language (YQL); I just want to ask, is it possible to inject SQL in this YQL query?*

Comment: we can't tell you whether a given endpoint is vulnerable just from one example.

Comment: Thanks, @tao_oat. Looking further, I found this's not vulnerable because that was the design of YQL, which has been created to not vulnerable with SQL Injection. There was a report about this from Nahamsec (if you know) and it has been marked as not vulnerable. Also, the website is Yahoo! (Verizon Media).